# Nodejs - Calling a method from other file properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm new to this domain and want to fix this error, I have two classes, 'Ticket.js' where I put my routes and 'support.js' where my websockets methods are declared, 
I just want to use the method delared in 2nd file in 1st file,
here's the strucutre of code of both files :

```
class SupportTicketRouter  {
.
.
.
    sendMessagesSocket = (req, res, next) => {
        const SUPPORT_SOCKET = require('app/routes/socket/support');
        const MESSAGES       = req.api.support.messages;

        SUPPORT_SOCKET.sendModifiedTicket(MESSAGES);

        next();
    }
}
```

in the other file :

```
const SUPPORT_SOCKET = (MQTT_CLIENT, REDIS_CLIENT, IO_SERVER, IO_CLIENT) => {

   // EntryPoints

   // Exit points
   SUPPORT_SOCKET.sendModifiedTicket = (data) => {
       IO_SERVER.in(data[0]._id).emit('OneTicketReload', data);
       Logger.info('%s%s', 'Ticket sent to room ', data[0]._id);
   };
```

so basically I just want to call sendModifiedTicket from other file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem specifically? Calling the other function from different file shouldn't be a problem for you I am guessing, so please clarify what exactly are you seeking help with.

Comment: I get this error when calling the function : Property 'sendModifiedTicket' does not exist on type

Comment: is it being exported properly? console.log the variable in your 2nd file where you are calling the other function

Comment: that's the problem, I'm not exporting correctly and I don't know how to fix it, in my second file I have this in end of the file 'module.exports = SUPPORT_SOCKET;' so I guessed it was enough to get the methods in 1st file just by calling 'const SUPPORT_SOCKET = require('app/routes/socket/support');

Comment: Are you sure you are locating the file correctly? Update the question with Folder structure and your exports code along with you requiring that function in other file.

Answer (score 1):

You should export your function from a file where it is defined:

```
module.exports = SUPPORT_SOCKET
```

then include it wherever you want to use it:

```
const supportSocket = require('./path-to-js-file').
class SupportTicketRouter  {...
```

this also may help:
https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/2016/06/13/NodeJS-How-to-Use-Functions-from-Another-File-using-module-exports.html

Comment: I already did this , but i'm getting this error 
'Property 'sendModifiedTicket' does not exist on type '(MQTT_CLIENT: any, REDIS_CLIENT: any, IO_SERVER: any, IO_CLIENT: any) => void''
I guess it's because I have a method inside another one , sendModifiedTicket inside SUPPORT_TICKET !

Comment: when trying to acces sendModifiedTicket I get this error : "SUPPORT_SOCKET.sendModifiedTicket is not a function"

Comment: if you have more than one exports inside file where SUPPORT_SOCKET is defined, then when you import method, put the name of the const inside curly braces: const { supportSocket } = require('./path-to-js-file');

Answer (score 0):

Controller.js

```
export class Controller {
   constructor(){ 
        this.method  = this.method.bind(this)
   }

    method (req, res) {....}
}
```

OtherFile.js

```js
function otherMethod () {
     const controller = new Controller();
     controller.method()
}
```